# Liferay hook, jsp does not compile on glassfish

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I want to add language selection support on the dockbar in my Liferay 6.1.0 ga1 instance bundled with glassfish, but when compiling(even original files) some errors occurs:

```
    Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 432 in the jsp file: /html/portlet/dockbar/view.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method containsWithoutViewableGroup(com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionChecker,com.liferay.portal.model.Layout,<nulltype>,boolean,java.lang.String)
  location: class com.liferay.portal.service.permission.LayoutPermissionUtil

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 450 in the jsp file: /html/portlet/dockbar/view.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method containsWithoutViewableGroup(com.liferay.portal.security.permission.PermissionChecker,com.liferay.portal.model.Layout,<nulltype>,boolean,java.lang.String)
  location: class com.liferay.portal.service.permission.LayoutPermissionUtil

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
/view_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.


    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:316)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:120)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.doInclude(PortletRequestProcessor.java:281)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.doForward(PortletRequestProcessor.java:251)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:341)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.process(PortletRequestProcessor.java:230)
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.include(StrutsPortlet.java:239)
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.doView(StrutsPortlet.java:152)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.doDispatch(LiferayPortlet.java:211)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:651)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:722)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1182)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:534)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.renderPortlet(PortalImpl.java:4735)
    at com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil.renderPortlet(PortalUtil.java:1455)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:213)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:135)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletImpl.processPortlet(RuntimePortletImpl.java:122)
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePortletUtil.processPortlet(RuntimePortletUtil.java:54)
    at com.liferay.taglib.portletext.RuntimeTag.doTag(RuntimeTag.java:111)
    at com.liferay.taglib.portletext.RuntimeTag.doTag(RuntimeTag.java:63)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.VelocityTaglib.runtime(VelocityTaglib.java:597)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.VelocityTaglib.runtime(VelocityTaglib.java:591)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.doInvoke(UberspectImpl.java:389)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:378)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:270)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:262)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:342)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:72)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.VelocimacroProxy.render(VelocimacroProxy.java:212)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.directive.RuntimeMacro.render(RuntimeMacro.java:247)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTDirective.render(ASTDirective.java:175)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:72)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIfStatement.render(ASTIfStatement.java:87)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:336)
    at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:328)
    at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:235)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:381)
    at com.liferay.portal.velocity.VelocityEngineImpl.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineImpl.java:184)
    at com.liferay.portal.velocity.VelocityEngineImpl.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineImpl.java:194)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.velocity.VelocityEngineUtil.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngineUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.includeVM(ThemeUtil.java:409)
    at com.liferay.taglib.util.ThemeUtil.include(ThemeUtil.java:99)
    at com.liferay.taglib.theme.IncludeTag.doEndTag(IncludeTag.java:39)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspx_meth_liferay$1theme_include_1(portal_jsp.java:450)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.common.themes.portal_jsp._jspService(portal_jsp.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:300)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:79)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.doForward(PortalRequestProcessor.java:280)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:302)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:174)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:533)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:510)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:454)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:300)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:135)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:304)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:201)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:241)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:113)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:55)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:240)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:208)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:203)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:105)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:164)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:184)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Source code for html/portlet/dockbar/view.jsp at 432 lines:

```
<c:if test="<%= (!SitesUtil.isLayoutUpdateable(layout) || (layout.isLayoutPrototypeLinkActive() && !group.hasStagingGroup())) && LayoutPermissionUtil.containsWithoutViewableGroup(themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker(), layout, null, false, ActionKeys.UPDATE) %>">
```

and 450:

```
<c:if test="<%= !(group.isLayoutPrototype() || group.isLayoutSetPrototype() || group.isUserGroup()) && layoutTypePortlet.isCustomizable() && LayoutPermissionUtil.containsWithoutViewableGroup(permissionChecker, layout, null, false, ActionKeys.CUSTOMIZE) %>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LayoutPermissionUtil` is a class that's supposed to be on the global classpath, among the so-called "dependencies". Maybe you did an upgrade and forgot to upgrade those classes - or installed them in a non-matching version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used another version(6.1.1) of source code of Liferay, and deploy to the 6.1.0